# What would be an appropriate job title, based on the work I do?

Tags: title

I'm having a bit of a problem with describing my job position. I need to name my position due to several reasons, but i find it very hard to define it.

It's a small company, so i fit into multiple roles. Some of the jobs i do are:
My primary job is as a developer, and as far as that part goes i'm doing Javascript and php(main application), c# and android.
But i also set up and maintain all of our equipment(databases, virtualization cluster, network, VoIP, AD, exchange, web servers).

I'm currently going with Head of IT/Senior developer, but i find that a bit confusing. The problem is, we have 3 people in the company (with another 50 in another company that use our servers, but have no IT knowledge, and depend on me to keep their stuff running), so it's not really a managerial position since i only manage myself. There are 3 people in the company, but the other 2 are developers only, while my job is primarily to keep everything running, and develop when i have time.

Any ideas? And sorry if it's a bad question, but i have run out of ideas :P

P.S. About 2/3 of my job consist of development, while 1/3 is general IT work.

Comment: Primary IT?, it's used here for the head of an IT dept (not manager although they apparently do manager type stuff sometimes) in Govt. Can't say I've actually seen one do much work, but that's their title.

Comment: Full Stack developer will be a good name

Comment: Note: If this is for a resume or something similar, *definitely* include a full comprehensive list of your job roles, responsibilities, and activities, even if you feel they are not necessarily 'your' responsibilities - showing that you've taken responsibitiles beyond what is expected of you is a *good* thing, and you should include it at any and all opportunities.

Comment: Go with your HR -- what job title were you hired for / under?

Comment: @CubeJockey There is no HR. There's 4 people. 2 Developers, me, and a boss that knew me from my previous company and knew what i know. There was no talk about position. Only job requirements. That's why i'm in this mess :P we need to make business cards, email signatures and such, but we have no idea what to name my position :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds a bit like you work as some sort of DevOp

> DevOps (a clipped compound of development and operations) is a culture, movement or practice that emphasizes the collaboration and communication of both software developers and other information-technology (IT) professionals while automating the process of software delivery and infrastructure changes.

Your job fit into this description. You do development & IT. Maybe that should be title to go by?

Comment: You provided an answer, so you did the right thing.  And it's a better answer than mine...

Comment: Thx for this. I'm going with DevOps engineer for now. Mailed it to the boss and awaiting response :P

Comment: no problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something along the lines of

**IT Architect**

or

**Systems Architect**

These seem to fit the bill and "Architect" is ambiguous enough to describe both of your roles without being misleading.

Comment: Architecture is specialized work.

Answer (score 1):

**IT Generalist**.  You do a little of this, a little of that.  But a word of caution: generalists, over time, don't see increases in their income as much as specialists.  You can have a specialist title, but the work you actually do tells all.

Comment: It's a transition position. I have 7 years experience in server management, but i want to switch to development. This job offered me a way to switch to a developer, while offering me an increase in pay due to them not needing a system administrator as well as developer. The only other way to switch would have been to go for a beginner job in development while taking a massive pay cut.