# What should my workplace title be based on what I do - It's currently Digital Marketing

Tags: resume, job-search, salary, job-description, title

I work for a dealership, I am not ready to leave any time soon (I am back in school for computer science, and they are very flexible with my school schedule) -  However, I would like to know what title best fits for the work that I do.  I feel my resume and my LinkedIn profiles do not accurately reflect the many hats I wear for this company.

I'll list the more relevant tasks to the role - stuff no one else can or would do otherwise.

- Create Email using Mailchimp - Content creation, design, and reporting - light HTML/CSS
- Upload and segment leads from our Sales CRM into Mailchimp - I chose which segments receive a message
- Create and maintain an annual marketing and event calendar
- Create Social Media Content
- Optimize web content, such as inventory pages and written content - light HTML/CSS
- Work with outside developer team to request edits needed to site and new functionality needed on our site
- Work with Ad Agency to ensure they are pushing the web campaigns that matter most to our business
- Design media and send to print while maintaining brand and manufacturer identity guidelines
- Submit marketing co-op proposals to manufacturers for potential reimbursement
- Coordinate event planning - Create Eventbrite page, book hotels based on what the stakeholder needs.
- Assist staff with in-house technical support (printers, computer quirks, new software training)
- Technical on-boarding and off-boarding (setup new emails and distribution lists)
- Creation of automated processes for the business (custom-coded google forms)
- Setup new devices (ipads)
- I do not **typically** setup new computers or run network connections, we have another techie person and he takes the lead, but I am back up if he is not available.

**Extra Credit:**
In your opinion, What should this role be earning in Chicago? I report directly to the business owner. I do not hold a college degree, but I do have 10 years+ experience doing this type of work between this company and the previous one I was at. The company is about 30 employees

Comment: Use the title that your company gave you, as that is your official title.  You can still list all of your responsibilities and accomplishments.

Comment: Its a small enough place that I kind of gave it to myself and I'm introduced as a bunch of different things pretty regularly. Also, because of my lack of education and thus my imposter syndrome, I do not advocate enough for myself.  I am pretty sure I am underpaid, and I know they'd respond if I asked for more.  I just don't know whats fair.  I am planning on negotiating a pay raise by way of tuition reimbursement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be an appropriate job title, based on the work I do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76918/what-would-be-an-appropriate-job-title-based-on-the-work-i-do)

Comment: You are a Social Media/Marketing Associate II.

Comment: @AlexM thanks for your input, I'll look into salary ranges based on that.

Comment: @JazzmanJim, unfortunately that doesn't line up with the role I am in.  But I appreciate your looking out.

Answer (score 1):

**At small companies/departments, titles rarely encompass all tasks.**

My team consists of people who officially have the title of Software Developer. But because there are not a lot of us, some of us also serve as devops and DBAs.

My company is larger than yours at about 500 people. As a consequence, the tasks you do are spread over three different departments in two different buildings.

Focus on the responsibilities you do the most and the responsibilities you want to have in a future job (or be judged on in your current job). In a 30 person company, you probably don't spend much time setting up iPads.

The title I would create in this situation is *Marketing Operations Director.*

Marketing is your primary skill. Just forget about the tech support as it is fairly low-level help desk stuff. Include the "Creation of automated processes for the business (custom-coded google forms)" under marketing.